# Looking for the name of a definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a set that ordered, where you can add / subtract scalar values to but cannot multiply /divide against them, what is the set called? Is it just ordered?

Comment: If you can add scalrs, this seems to be an affine 1-space? That's like a copy of $\Bbb R$, but you forget where the $0$ is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean a linearly ordered Abelian group.

This is just an Abelian group $(G,+,-,0)$, with a linear order $\le$ such that 
the group structure and the order behave nicely together:

- $\forall g,h, k \in G : g \le h \rightarrow g+ k \le h +k$
- $\forall g,h \in G: g \le h \rightarrow -h \le -g$.

You can also generalise to just groups and partial orders (e.g. ordered topological vector spaces etc.) See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group)  e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are thinking of closure. A set has closure under an operation if that operation on the members of the set always produces another member of that same set.

So, I think you are saying that you have a set that is closed under scalar addition but not closed under scalar multiplication.